# in windows, how to associate a context menu to a FILE NAME (not by extension) ?

Tags: windows, contextmenu

i want to be able to right-click a file (e.g. "setup.py"), and run actions on it, with arguments.

(in my case: execute the command "python setup.py install" on it, at the that location.)

i do not want to associate ALL *.py files, it just clutters the context menu.

is that all possible?

Answer (score 1):

ok , i got it working.

(official docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

the answer is to add "appliesTo" string key to the file's type registry entry.

In my case, it was:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\setup]
"AppliesTo"="setup.py"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\setup\command]
@="d:\\\\utils\\\\set-up-python-and-pause.bat"
```

and for completeness sake (irelevant to this question) - set-up-python-and-pause.bat:

```
python setup.py install
pause
```

Comment: Note that this will also trigger for "awesome setup.py". You need `System.FileName:=setup.py` if you want exactly `setup.py`.